# How to get the date of last change from multiple Django models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

The environment is Django 4 and Python 3.10+. In the application there are multiple data models, each with 'created' and 'modified' DateTimeFields. I need to get the timestamp of last data modification - either creation of new object or modification of a existing one, for cache invalidation.

Currently the code checks for the newest creation timestamp and is like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max

qs_1 = Model_1.objects.all() 
qs_2 = Model_2.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('created')
qs_3 = Model_3.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('created')  

last = max(list((itertools.chain(list(queryset.aggregate(Max('created')).values())
                                 for queryset in (qs_1, qs_2, qs_3)
                                 if queryset.count()))))[0]
```

My questions are as follows:

1. The expression to get the last creation date is quite convoluted. Is there a way to compute the latest timestamp over multiple models using the ORM alone? It can be done in pure SQL, so it should be possible in the ORM.
2. How do I extend it to also compare the `modified` fields of the models?